# Android Listen to events from Library Module

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am creating a library on Android using **EventBus**.

I am posting an event in my library.

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new ConnectToDataEvent(Constants.AUTH,true));
```

The app module is registered to listen for events.

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

The Subscribe method:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(ConnectToDataEvent event) {

    loginonClick();
  };
```

I am receiving

```
No subscribers registered for event
```

Is this the right way to use in a library or it is not possible at all?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> No subscribers registered for event

This is usually because your Activity is not visible anymore, so the `onStop()` is already called and the EventBus has already been unsubcribed.

You need to remove the `onStop()` part and try moving the unregister part to `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```